# Boto region_name missing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have tried various attempts to estalish a connection to an S3 compatible service but I keep getting an error. The following code throws the error below. Any ideas?

```
import os 
import boto
import boto.s3.connection
from boto.s3.key import Key

try:

    conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region(region = 'nil',
    aws_access_key_id = 'xx',
    aws_secret_access_key = 'xx',
    host = 'ds41s3-scs.xx.com',
    calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
    )

    response = s3.list_buckets()

except Exception,e:
    print str(e)
    print "error"
```

The error:

```
TypeError: connect_to_region() missing 1 required positional argument: 'region_name'
```

Comment: You might also want to look at clients designed for S3-compatible services, such as: https://github.com/minio/minio-py

Answer (score 1):

Why is the `region` set to `nil`? The signature of `connect_to_region` is:

```
boto.s3.connect_to_region(region_name, **kw_params)
```

You are missing the mandatory argument: `region_name`

Comment: The S3 service I use doens't have regions. I also tried to use region_name instead of just region but it shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Go for latest version of AWS SDK for python (boto3) which supports latest features

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')

response = client.list_buckets()
```